# Cholesky factorization

Tags: matlab, matrix, factorization

within a matlab code of mine, I have to deal with the Cholesky factorization of a certain given matrix. I am generally calling `chol(A,'lower')` to generate the lower triangular factor.

Now, checking my code with the `profiler`, it is evident that function `chol` is really time consuming, especially if the size of the input matrix becomes large.

Therefore, I would like to know, if there is any valuable alternative to the built-in `chol` function.

I have been thinking of the `LAPACK` library, and namely of `spptrf` function. Is it available in `MATLAB` or not?

Any hint or support are more than welcome.

**EDIT**

Just as an example, the profiler retrieves this information:

[image]

where `Coh_u` has size `(1395*1395)`. It has, also, to be remarked that `chol` is called `4000` times, since I need the cholesky factor for `4000` different configurations.

Comment: Behind the scenes Matlab generally uses high-quality numeric libraries which are equal (broadly-speaking) in accuracy, precision and speed to off-the-shelf libraries such as BLAS, LAPACK, etc.  Indeed in some cases Matlab uses those libraries.  It's highly likely, but I haven't checked, that their implementation of `chol` uses such code.  Better programmers than I (though perhaps not better than you) have tried to implement (in some way) faster implementations of Matlab's numeric routines and failed miserably.

Comment: at the moment I'm comparing my code's performances with another one, written in `fortran` and making use of lapack `spptrf`. The feelinf is that `spptrf` is drastically faster then `chol`, though you always need to be cautious in comparing similar codes in two different language. I have the suspect the `MATLAB` internally calls `LAPACK` library, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of matlab you are using, but I found [this discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/146786), which suggests in older versions that Cholesky Factorization was very slow as you're describing.

One of the answers there says to use the [CHOLMOD package or SuiteSparse](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/1252-suitesparse-umfpack-cholmod-and-many-other-matlab-built-in-functions), which has a `chol2` function that is supposed to be faster.

Comment: I'm using the latest release of Matlab, therefore `CHOLMOD` should be already implemented. or I think so!

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if the correct expression for `Coh_u` is as under

a) `Coh_u = exp(-a.*sqrt((f(ii)/Uhub).^2 + (0.12/Lc).^2)).*(df.*psd(ii,1));`

or

b) `Coh_u = exp(-a.*dist*sqrt((f(ii)/Uhub).^2 + (0.12/Lc).^2)).*(df.*psd(ii,1));`

The difference in a) and b) is that in b) `dist` has been added which is the distance between two matrices `Y` an `Z` such that

```
dist = pdist2([Y(:) Z(:)],[Y(:) Z(:)]);
```

But it leads into the "Matrix not positive definite" error with the `chol()` function.